# [git commit without message]: how to get out from it

Tags: git

Is there anyone who can help me getting rid of this?

[image]

It came up to my console after typing "git commit". I know I should have to provide a comment. But the problem now is that I don't know exactly what is it and particularly I can not get out of this and I can't continue with my console

Comment: `^G` stands for Ctrl-G. Figure out the rest.

Comment: At the bottom you see your options. You can write the commit with `^O` and close it with `^X`.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50920577/3697120

Answer (score -1):

Please try escape followed by `!wq`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: The advice is for `vim` editor. The topicstarter uses `nano` editor with completely different keys. PS. Even for `vim` you answer is wrong; the command is `:wq` — no exclamation mark!